# Wordpress custom post plugin blank screen when saving posts

Tags: php, wordpress

** EDIT **

I removed some spaces that were present after the `?>` which solved the problem.

**

I've created a simple plugin for custom posts, when I save or update a post within the custom post editor rather than revert back to the post editor (like a normal Wordpress post) the screen goes blank. It does update the post, no problem there.

Is there an option I've forgotten to include in my code:

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'packages_post' );

function packages_post() {
  register_post_type( 'packages',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Packages',
            'singular_name' => 'Packages',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Package',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Package',
            'new_item' => 'New Package',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Package',
            'search_items' => 'Search Package',
            'not_found' => 'No Packages found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Packages found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Package'
        ),

        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( '/menu-logo.png', __FILE__ ),
        'has_archive' => false
    )
);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all your php files for white space at the end of a php file.

i.e.

```
);
}

?>
```

The `?>` has white space/new break after it (In my example). You will most likely have some in a random `.php` file that is being used/included.

Comment: Better yet, never end a PHP file with "?>". Just omit that close tag altogether and you'll be safe and never have to worry about the white space issue.